# WordPress CSS does not persist throughout the site

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm working on a clients site in WordPress using the Calafate theme. The client needs the carousel images to each link to a certain blog post on the site. The only problem is that the theme creates two large divs that cover the carousel. So with CSS I create some extra space and give the images a link. The only problem here is that when a user goes to another page on the site, it's as if the CSS just reverts back to the original before I even touched it, and now the two divs blocking the carousel is back. I've never experienced this before so I have no clue where to start.

Client site: https://idapostle.com/

### Problem

Home page CSS does not persist throughout users time on site. But if user refreshes the site, correct CSS returns.

Comment: Do the latest CSS updates remain after the user refreshes or does the problem perpetuate the same cycle again? Have you ruled out caching? Clear the WP Rocket *site cache* to be sure - then check in an incognito browser (*Shift+CTRL+N*), or use the chrome "Guest" account, to rule out any *browser caching*.

Comment: Site reverts back to the modified css (the correct css) if the user refreshes.  I have not ruled out caching but that would make sense. I'll go ahead and check it out thank you.

Comment: If a user goes back to the home page via browser history, the CSS is correct. But if the user decides to use the brand logo in the top left corner, then WordPress is serving up a different version of the home page. Would this be caching? I've cleared the site cache via WP Rocket plugin but it still continues.